# Cannot open the file manager in 19.04

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, 19.04

The nautilus file manager stopped working recently and I have no idea why. 
I click on the icon and it appears to try to start, but then nothing happens.

It makes no difference if I try to start it from the command line.

I have tried reinstalling it and updating everything I can find to update. No change.

Comment: What output you get if you launch it from terminal ?

Comment: Nothing happens at all. No output

Comment: I have now purged nautilus and then reinstalled it. This also makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

Execute this command in terminal. Worked for me.

```
tracker reset -r
```

For some reason, nautilus doesn't work without tracker.

nautilus is the file manager and tracker helps in searching of files.

Benefits of tracker: -

```
It speeds up searching for files in the Files app.

It enables full-text search in the Files app. In other words, you can look for files that contain specific words, instead of searching just by filename.

It allows the Batch Rename feature in the Files app able to rename based on file metadata. For instance, you can use the Artist name for properly tagged music files as part of the new filename.

It enables file and folder search in the Activities Overview on GNOME.
```

Why it stops working?
I don't know, yet.

Comment: Please don't just trow a command and say "Run this" without explanation. Why will `tracker reset -r` solve OPs problem ?